# How To Save a PDF

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf

Hi I have a pdf generating and it downloads to the computer fine when I click the button. However I need that file to save to a folder within my system.

I have tried a load of different approaches but i cant get any to work right is there anything that can save it to a PDF folder created within my website on visual studio

Updated Code

```
    Partial Class Pages_Payment
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page 



Protected Sub btnExport_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click
        btnPayment.Visible = False

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Receipt_" & Session("InvoNo") & ".pdf")

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

    Dim sw As New StringWriter()

    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

    pnlPerson.RenderControl(hw)

    Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())

    Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 100.0F, 0.0F)

    Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
    pdfDoc.Open()

    htmlparser.Parse(sr)


    pdfDoc.Close()

    Response.Write(pdfDoc)

    Response.End()


    Pages_Payment.SavePDF("~/PDF/Mypdf.pdf", pdfDoc)


End Sub

Public Shared Sub SavePDF(virtualPath As String, document As Document)
    Dim msOutput As New MemoryStream()
    Dim writer As New PdfWriter(document, msOutput)
    Dim filebytes As Byte() = msOutput.ToArray()
    Dim path As String = Server.MapPath(virtualPath)
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, filebytes)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: To clarify, you want to save the PDF on the server somewhere?

Comment: yea so it would be like ("~/PDF/") as where i want the file to go

Comment: If its iTextSharp, see here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948053/save-pdf-to-disc

Comment: Im trying to add this to my code but i have know idea that all that stamper, reader stuff means to know if im even adding it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically PdfWriter hooked up to a MemoryStream. Convert the MemoryStream to a byte array, then save the bytes to a file.

```
    Protected Sub btnExport_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click
    'btnPayment.Visible = False
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Receipt_" & Session("InvoNo") & ".pdf")
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    pnlPerson.RenderControl(hw)
    Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
    Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 100.0F, 0.0F)
    Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
    Dim msOutput As New MemoryStream()
    Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, msOutput)    
    pdfDoc.Open()
    htmlparser.Parse(sr)
    pdfDoc.Close()
    Dim filebytes As Byte() = msOutput.ToArray()
    Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~/PDF/mypdf.pdf")
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, filebytes)
    Response.BinaryWrite(filebytes)
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the reply im looking in to converting to a byte array im really unfamiliar with this whole area so i will try anything :)

Comment: I pasted that in but its highlighting an issue with writer   -- Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class. F:\BSNC\Pages\Payment.aspx.vb 206 30 F:\BSNC\

Comment: Overload resolution failed because no 'New' is accessible. is the writer error sorry  the other one is on the server. line

Comment: thanks but these errors are in the `Public Shared Sub SavePDF(virtualPath As String, document As Document)` block on dim writer and then =server.mappath

Comment: i can see what you mean but its giving an error on the screen so it wont run i get a compilation error for both lines

Comment: I put that in also but the two errors remain on Dim writer as  and server.mappath as before

Comment: Verify that your SavePDF function matches the one in my answer. I had change it from a static function to an instance function.

Comment: oh sorry i missed that bit. ok it seems to be replacing the file mypdf.pdf by looking at the time stamp now so thats a lot of progress thank you so much. it wont open the file because adobe says its not a valid format even though the download shows it fine. im hoping that will be something simple to solve :)

Comment: yea it just generates a blank file! nightmare question this has been

Comment: you are a genius thank you so much it works perfect now. I really appreciate the time and effort my IT dissertation just got so much better. Thank you  :)